# ERROR:Output file #0 does not contain any stream (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to make a thumbnail image from mp4 video using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) but I am getting the error that

> Output #0, image2, to 'output.jpg':
>
> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

the command I used is

```
ffmpeg -i file_example_MP4_700KB.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -vf thumbnail,scale=200:115 -qscale:v 2 -frames:v 1 -f image2 -c:v mjpeg output.jpg
```

and I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I stuck throw it for so long.
Any suggestions will be good

I am using Ubuntu 18.*

full logs:-

```
ffmpeg version n4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
 configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable- libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3':
Metadata:
genre           : Cinematic
album           : YouTube Audio Library
title           : Impact Moderato
artist          : Kevin MacLeod
Duration: 00:00:27.25, start: 0.034531, bitrate: 224 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : LAME3.99r
Output #0, image2, to 'output.jpg':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: Show full log..

Comment: i mentioned the full log

Comment: Your input (`file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3`) has no video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with:

```sh
ffmpeg -i myfile.raw -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le output.mp3
```

The solution was to change the order to:

```sh
ffmpeg -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le -i input.raw output.mp3`
```